# Generating synthetic data based on mean, skewness, standard deviation and autocorrelation

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, statsmodels, pandas

Given that I have the mean, standard deviation, skewness and autocorrelation,
How do I generate 1000 years of random data based on the above parameters in python or Matlab?

I know for example I can use Scipy's skewnorm to generate data based on the mean, std and skewness alone. I can also generate data with Autoceralation by developing an AR model. Am just not sure how to combine the two or if there is a much simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First generate independent data X(1), X(2), ... with mean zero, variance 1, and the desired skewness, e.g. from gamma, Weibull, skew-normal or other distrtibution (you will have to linearly transform to fix the mean and variance).

Then you set Z(t) = r*X(t-1) +X(t), where r is your desired autocorrelation.

Then linearly transfrom Z(t) to get the desired mean and variance.

This works if you have defined skew in the standard way that is affine-invariant.